# Get rotation of an image selected from the gallery on activity result on android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, exif, image-rotation

this question seems to come up often, I've read a lot on this subject my question is when i select an image from the gallery and pass it to on activity result the orientation is wrong, so i want to read it and correct it so it is always portrait,
I've implemented methods that work for launching the camera, taking a picture, and checking the Exif data to make sure its always portrait but this doesn't seem to work for selecting images for the gallery my rotation variable will always return 0

```
 ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
 int rotation =
        exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);
        System.out.println(rotation);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        if (rotation != 0f) {

            matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);
            Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0,
            0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
            matrix,false);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
            path = saveToInternalStorage(imageFileName,bitmap2,getApplicationContext());
            }
            else
            path = saveToInternalStorage(imageFileName,bitmap,getApplicationContext());
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

ExifToDegrees method

```
    private static int exifToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {
    if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
        return 90;
    }
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
        return 180; }
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
        return 270; }
    else if (exifOrientation == 6) {
        return 90; }
    else if (exifOrientation == 3) {
        return 180; }
    else if (exifOrientation == 8) {
        return 270; }
    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned I've read a lot about this, some say its a bug with android some say its down to the new recent's file picker and we should use

```
    getAbsolutePath()
```

and be checking for each SDK version and be saving the image first, I've done all of these with no joy some say we don't need to be using Exif at all and that

```
  MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION
```

should work, but again this hasn't worked.

I'm targeting devices from ICS to M (I have all permissions I need granted) I'm saving the image to my folder

```
  File directory = cw.getDir("SimpleAAC", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and saving the path in a database, i load the images from that folder, using the path from my database and using universal image loader, 
after asking for permission i launch gallery with this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, 
                    "Select A Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                    dialog.dismiss();
```

here is my onActivityResult code for the gallery

```
 if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=  
 null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

            BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new   
            BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 4;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            Bitmap scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, 
            null, bitmapOptions);
            String timeStamp = new 
            SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = timeStamp + ".jpg";

        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("SimpleAAC", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File mypath = new File(directory,imageFileName);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //the relevant parts of this method(setThumbNailImageAndSave ) are 
        //  included above      


        finalPath = setThumbnailImageAndSave(imageView,mypath);
        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        DisplayImageOptions options = new  
        DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_insert_photo_black_24dp)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_insert_photo_black_24dp)
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_insert_photo_black_24dp).build();

        imageLoader.displayImage(finalPath, imageView, options);
        System.out.println(finalPath);
    }
```

So to conclude this question I'm looking for clarification, is this a bug? can i get around this using MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION and if so how? is it the intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)? is it the post kitkat file changes?

Honestly I've read so much contradicting information on this and nothing i seem to try works, thanks for any and all replies

Comment: Why don't you just measure the width and height. if the width if larger than the height you could assume it was take in landscape.

Comment: Been there my friend thanks for the reply, this doesn't work for quite a few devices but is definitely plan b @Eugene H

Comment: It Worked for me.. ! Solved Solution
[Solved : How to rotate image to its default orientation selected from gallery in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758952/solved-how-to-rotate-image-to-its-defauld-orientation-selected-from-gallery-in)

Comment: @nightcoder there are a bunch of devices that this approach doesn't work for the best way I've found is to copy the bytes to a file then you have full access to all data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is this a bug?

In your code? Possibly. It is unclear how `imgFile` in your first code snippet relates to your last code snippet. But you are stripping all the EXIF headers by decoding the bitmap, then encoding it, in that last code snippet. If that is the file that you are examining via `ExifInterface` in your first code snippet, that's your problem.

> can i get around this using MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION and if so how?

No, because your image may not come from the `MediaStore`.

Instead, given your `uri`, call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`. Then, pass that `openInputStream()` to [a better `ExifInterface`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/31/tale-two-exifinterfaces.html), one that can read from streams rather than requiring a file. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/EXIFRotater) demonstrates the process, including having a copy of the better `ExifInterface` code, though I happen to use an `InputStream` from assets rather than from a `ContentResolver`.

If you want to make a local copy of the image for other reasons, then get rid of the decode-and-encode the bitmap logic in that last code snippet. Instead, `openInputStream()` with that `uri`, open a `FileOutputStream` on your desired file, and copy the bytes using normal Java I/O. This will keep the EXIF headers intact.

Also, in either scenario, please do all this `Uri` work on a background thread.

Comment: Genius thank you so much, I had read alot of what you've mentioned such as losing the exif info on decoding the bitmap, I'll get on this in the morning thanks again

Comment: Maybe now I can stop all these shenanigans

Comment: or maybe not ive been reading since your post checking out your demo project and some of your many other posts and honestly i just dont understand it at all, and what you said about copying the bytes from output stream to file is also beyond me

Comment: DONE!!! Thanks again @CommonsWare used the copying bytes to files approach and its now working thank you soooooooooooooo much